# Does the calculation correct for bin to dec?

Tags: java, binary

`00101`=5 digits, disregard two Zeros and calculate

```
0+(5-2-1)^2 = 4 
4+(5-3-1)^2 = 5 
5+(5-4-1)^2 = 5
```

final answer Is it Correct?

```
char[] charArray = binary.toCharArray(); 
double answer = 0; 
for (double index = 0; index < charArray.length; index++)
{
   if (charArray[(int)index] == '1')
   {
      answer = answer + Math.pow(2.0, (charArray.length - index - 1));
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `int` instead of `double` and use `1 >> (charArray.length - index - 1)` instead of `pow`.

Comment: @johnchen902 can you post is please

Comment: @johnchen902 i guess somethings wrong.. the output is 1 only

Comment: Oops, a typo: change `>>` to `<<`. Luckily I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt` , that converts your String to int using base two:

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
```

Refer this:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Your expected results are being calculated as if the binary string is read from right to left; however, your code is reading the binary string from left to right.

You can also try this:

```
char[] charArray = binary.toCharArray(); 
double answer = 0; 
for (double index = charArray.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
{
     if (charArray[(int)index] == '1') 
     {
          answer = answer + Math.pow(2.0, index);
     }
}
```

Comment: The code is right.. now i have to know how it calculate... i have to defend this code to understand

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the Wheel. Use following simple code.

```
  int dec=Integer.valueOf(binStr, 10);//Here 10 is base.
```

Comment: i should have not make shortcuts. its better to do functions

Comment: Do by you own function is good for learning, but not good for performance or production.